# Where to find 478 motherboard circuit schematics?

Tags: computers

I have searched for 478 motherboard circuit schematics on the internet, but have found none. Are any available publicly?

Comment: You might have some luck searching for a "reference design"

Comment: @Joby Taffey - Tried your recommendation, still no luck; will look around some more with the term though before giving up.

Comment: "478"? Do you mean Socket 478, or Intel Pentium 4 X86 Motherboards? If so , I am interested in the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't hold out much hope.  I've looked at motherboards and while they don't look complicated per se the sheer size of the design (number of nets) is bound to be daunting.  Plus I imagine the file format of the schematics will be for a rather high-powered schematic capture program costing several thousands of dollars.  I see you didn't find much for reference designs.  You might have luck finding reference designs for each individual chip (sound codec, south bridge, north bridge, etc) on the board and looking for reference designs.  Ideally a motherboard should just be all of those designs put together, but I'm sure there's several hundred catches (matching impedance for long traces for instance).

Comment: Thank you. Part of the problem is that I am doing this on behalf of a friend, and do not know much about electronics myself. Any chance you have a url to a promising site/resource?

Comment: I'd find a motherboard that meets your specs, buy it and start identifying chips.  Look up the chip on the manufacturers site and look for datasheets.  Reference designs are sometimes there, sometimes separate.  If you're lucky they'll be PDF, if not, altium or some other schematic capture program.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with AngryEE -- it's unlikely you will find a complete schematic for a 478 motherboard.
However, would something slightly different, such as one of the following, be adequate for whatever it is you are trying to do?

If you are looking for the complete schematic for a relatively modern motherboard,
there are several "motherboards that run Linux" with a complete and freely-available schematic.
http://opencircuits.com/motherboards_that_run_Linux

If you are trying to lookup what all those pins in a (obsolete) 478 socket do,
perhaps you will find the answers in the datasheet for
"The Intel® Pentium® 4 Processor in the 478-pin Package socket".
http://www.intel.com/design/pentium4/datashts/249887.htm

Answer (score 0):

I, for one, have actually designed a motherboard based on an Intel CPU.  So I have some direct knowledge of how to get schematics.

Intel will give you schematics for their reference designs (which are very close to the Motherboards they actually sell).  But you need to get an agreement going with them that includes a Non-Disclosure-Agreement (NDA).  And Intel will only do that with you if they believe that there is a money-making opportunity for them.

But with the NDA signed, getting the schematics is easy.  All you do is ask your Intel contact person!